# How to add PHP, JavaScript and HTML in my WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to add HTML, PHP and JavaScript code to my WordPress page. I cannot figure out how to do this. I've tried multiple plugins, and these did not work the way I wanted it.

The code I want to add looks like this:

```
<?php //my php here ?> 
<script> //my JavaScript here</script>

<div class="

 <select id="Plaats" name="Plaats">
      <?php DropdownHotels(); ?>
 </select>

 <input type="text" id="test" name="van" placeholder="value1" value="
 <?php if (isset($_POST['asd'])){echo $_POST['asd'];} ?>" readonly>

    <script>
     var blabla = 0;
    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to build a template or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I want to add these codes in containers into my custom page, which already exists. Also, I am new to working with WordPress, this page is build by someone else.

Comment: Would recommend you to take a look at the Wordpress `theme structure` https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/. Otherwise, you can use external plugins like [Elementor](http://elementor.com) or [VisualComposer](https://visualcomposer.io) where you can use raw code. However, I would recommend the first option.

Answer (score -3):

XYZ PHP Code is the plugin I used for this. I was able to copy and paste a complete page. This plugin supports HTML, PHP and JavaScript/jQuery for me.